# Creating a multimodule directory assembly fails

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multimodule project containing three projects. I try to copy the content of `src/main/config` of each module to `target/benchmark/config` in the parent project directory.

```
parent
    pom.xml (second setup)
    /src/main/assembly/benchmark.xml
    /module1
    /module2
    /module3
    /aggregationparent
        pom.xml (first setup)
        /src/main/assembly/benchmark.xml
```

**The assembly descriptor contained in the parent (aggregation project) under `src/assembly/benchmark.xml`**

```xml
<formats>
    <format>dir</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <includes>
            <include>groupid:artifactid</include>
        </includes>
        <sources>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>src/main/config/*</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

**The assembly plugin call**

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/benchmark.xml</descriptor>
                <finalName>benchmark</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried this with two directory setups which both fail with different error messages:

1. The parent is in a separate directory referencing its modules via `../modulename`
   The result is:

   ```
   Building artifactid 1.0-SNAPSHOT
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------

   [assembly:single]
   The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
   o  'groupid:artifactid'

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   BUILD FAILURE
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total time: 4.187s
   Finished at: Mon May 06 18:28:59 CEST 2013
   Final Memory: 8M/104M
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (default-cli) on project projectname: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive benchmark: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]
   ```

   Here I guess the `../moduledir` referencing causes an error leading to unresolvable modules in the assembly plugin. Is this right? What am I doing wrong?
2. The parents pom is in the parent directory of the modules.
   Result:

   ```
   Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project *moduleid*: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]
   ```

   The Debug output shows me that the assembly plugin tries to find the assembly descriptor in the project root of **each** selected module instead of using the one supplied in the parent project? Is this intended? How can I tell it to use the parent one?

Comment: Why do you have 2 assembly files? It is sufficient to have one assembly descriptor and the call to assembly plugin should happen in the aggregation parent's pom.xml file.